# Extract columns within an XML tables using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, xml, beautifulsoup

I have multiple tables like the one below from MySQL datadump, each one represents a row in the database. I would to extract the following information in order to migrate it to a different database.

```
<table name="dashboard">
  <column name="id">1</column>
  <column name="timestamp">2009-10-09 15:10:30</column>
  <column name="config_offline">1</column>
  <column name="item1">0.00</column>
  <column name="item2">0.00</column>
</table>

<table name="orders">
  <column name="id">1</column>
  <column name="timestamp">2016-08-04 08:39:13</column>
  <column name="item">1</column>
  <column name="payment">Check</column>
  <column name="cost">175.00</column>
  <column name="paid">175.00</column>
  <column name="cancel">0</column>
  <column name="received">1</column>
</table>
```

Here is what I am currently trying:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("test.xml", "r") as markup:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, "xml")

for row in soup.find_all('column'):
    print(row.text)
with open("test.xml", "r") as markup:
soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, "xml")
# And I also try this, but this doesn't work neither. 
for row in soup.find_all('table'):
    for c in row.find_all('column'):
       print(c.text)
```

The problem with this approach right now I cannot differentiate between the two table names. Is there a way I can extract the information from the two different tables separately?

Comment: there is typo in your updated question, change the last line to `print(c.text)`

Answer (score 1):

You can find the specific table by specific attribute:

```
import bs4
div_test="""  
<table name="dashboard">
  <column name="id">1</column>
  <column name="timestamp">2009-10-09 15:10:30</column>
  <column name="config_offline">1</column>
  <column name="item1">0.00</column>
  <column name="item2">0.00</column>
</table>
<table name="orders">
  <column name="id">1</column>
  <column name="timestamp">2016-08-04 08:39:13</column>
  <column name="item">1</column>
  <column name="payment">Check</column>
  <column name="cost">175.00</column>
  <column name="paid">175.00</column>
  <column name="cancel">0</column>
  <column name="received">1</column>
</table>
"""
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(div_test)
table_dashboard = soup.find('table', {'name':"dashboard"})
table_orders = soup.find('table', {'name':"orders"})
print table_dashboard
print '\n'
print table_orders
```

output will give you `table_dashboard` and `table_orders`:

```
<table name="dashboard">
<column name="id">1</column>
<column name="timestamp">2009-10-09 15:10:30</column>
<column name="config_offline">1</column>
<column name="item1">0.00</column>
<column name="item2">0.00</column>
</table>


<table name="orders">
<column name="id">1</column>
<column name="timestamp">2016-08-04 08:39:13</column>
<column name="item">1</column>
<column name="payment">Check</column>
<column name="cost">175.00</column>
<column name="paid">175.00</column>
<column name="cancel">0</column>
<column name="received">1</column>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems obvious... iterate on the "table" tags first then for each "table" tag on its "column" tags.